# Matching 2 dictionaries and replacing values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary as below type -

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> myDict1;
```

I have another dictionary **myDict2** of same signature as **myDict1**.

**myDict1** and **myDict2** having same values.
e.g -

```
{"Data1", {1 , 0}};
```

After an operation **myDict2** is updated(or better say I am recieving myDict2 as a return value of an operation) and it contains value as given below -

```
{"Data1", {1 , 10}};
```

I have to update **myDict1** by matching the keys of **myDict2**.
here keys are string **"Data1"** and int **1**.

**NOTE: here only the value of inner dictionary changes.**

Can someone suggest how to do that in better way?

Comment: after which operation does the `myDict2` contain this values?

Comment: Why not use an enum for the value instead of a dictionary

Comment: @TheGeneral as myDict2 is same dictionary as myDict1 so the keys are same. but after some operation value of inner dictionary has been changed for myDict2. matching the keys of both the dictionary I need to update value of inner dictionary "myDict1".

Comment: @nfgallimore enum wont serve my purpose as I am recieving reponse as a dictionary

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar How many records do you have in each dictionary? Is it always one record in each?

Comment: Override the Dict1 with Dict2 Cloned copy.

Comment: @AD8 it could be multiple records

Comment: @Md.ParwezAkhtar How about user1672994's suggestion? `myDict1 = myDict2`?

Comment: @user1672994 i cannot clone it because multiple operations returns 'myDict2' type data.'myDict1' may contatin record which is not returned by 'myDict2'. I need to only replace the value of inner dictionary 'myDict1' when the keys of both dictionary matches.

I've simplified the question and gave example of only 1 record. but myDict1 may contain multiple data which is not available in myDict2. I need to retain updated value of inner dictionary as well as maintaining records of myDict1 which is not yet modified.

Comment: So what have you tried? The straight forward approach would be to iterate the key of your first dictionary, first the matching item in the second and then comparing the inner dictionaries. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @GiladGreen exactly what I was thinking of. but I am aware of comparing keys of simple dictionary. I dont know how to compare keys of outer dictionary as well as inner dictionary. e.g if its a dictionary like - Dictionary<int, int> i can compare keys of both dictionaries like 

foreach(var cId in myDict1)
                {
                   foreach (var Id in myDict1)
                    {
                       if (cId.Key == Id.Key)
                        {
                            
                       }
                    } 
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//sample data
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> myDict1 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>();            
myDict1.Add("data1", new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 0 }, { 2, 0 }, { 3, 0 } });
myDict1.Add("data10", new Dictionary<int, int> { { 2, 10 }, { 3, 11 }, { 4, 0 } });

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> myDict2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>();
myDict2.Add("data1", new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 1 }, {3, 1 }, { 4, 1 } });
myDict2.Add("data2", new Dictionary<int, int> { { 2, 0 } });

//here we will iterate only through common keys (that both dictionaries have it)
foreach(string commonKey in myDict1.Keys.Intersect(myDict2.Keys))
    foreach(int intKey in myDict1[commonKey].Keys.Intersect(myDict2[commonKey].Keys))
        myDict2[commonKey][intKey] = myDict1[commonKey][intKey];
```